# Casting pickle object to custom data type

Tags: python, class, types, casting, pickle

I have created a class, lets call it Person:

```
class Person(object):
    def __init__(self, name: str, lastname: str):
        self.name, self.lastname = name, lastname

    def Copy(self):
        return Person(self.name, self.lastname)
```

After creating an instance of the class I decided to save it to a pickle file.
now, after saving I want to create a new instance of the class with the data from the pickle file, like this:

```
with open("data.pkl", "rb") as data_file:
    David = pickle.load(data_file).Copy()
```

I expect this to work since the copy method was explicitly created to make a new instance instead of just making the new object point to the same memory location.
However, I get an error saying
 `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'Copy'`

I thought about casting it but simply casting like this:

```
David = Person(pickle.load(data_file)).Copy()
```

Also doesn't work because it wants to get the arguments of the init function and not to cast it...

if anyone could help that'd would be great because I have searched and didn't find a similar issue, or I couldn't explain it well enough in a sentence to find it... one of those lol

Comment: Apparently your pickle file actually contains a pickle of `None`, not a pickle of what you thought you pickled. You probably screwed something up while making it. We can't tell what your bug was.

Comment: Also, there is no "casting" going on anywhere, it's not really a relevant term in Python.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga what do you mean there is no casting? if I have 'obj' and I do 'str(obj)' what do you call that?

Comment: @user2357112 well that's weird because I indeed thought about it, and using the debugger I went to the point where I pickle it and the variables view showed that it is a "Person" object...